# Cloudbees dev cloud + Capybara-webkit(Qt) how to use?

Tags: qt, jenkins, cloudbees

I want to run capybara-webkit in cloudbees, but I met this error in `bundle`

```
SocketCommand.h:4:19: fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I want to install Qt.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

$ apt-get install libqt4-dev
apt-get: command not found
```

How to install Qt? jenkins-plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT libraries are already installed on DEV@Cloud slaves,
to install capybara gem, you need to set

```
QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

then run cloudbees ruby add-on script

```
curl -s -o use-ruby https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/ruby/use-ruby
RUBY_VERSION=1.9.3-p327
source ./use-ruby
```

and setup your build script to install dependencies

```
gem install --conservative bundler
bundle install
```

(or equivalent)